# jQuery How to remove class for each element?

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how to remove the `selected` class of the all `a` element of the list ? I tried

```
$("#navigation li a").removeClass("selected");
```

but it seems not to be working.

```
        $('#navigation li').hover(function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
        });

        <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="home"><a class="selected"></a></li>
            <li class="about"><a>text1</a></li>
            <li class="services"><a>text2</a></li>
            <li class="portfolio"><a>text3</a></li>
            <li class="contact"><a>text4</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have jquery setup correctly your example seems to be working.  I setup a fiddle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kpDTV/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is removing the `selected` class from the `li` you hover over, rather than the `a` within.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/eG8ZS/

Maybe another part of script is not working?